# Oracle Select For Update Skip Locked not locking data

Tags: oracle, select

We have a main table that will be access by a few concurrent thread trying to grab data from the table. We are thinking that using `SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` would be beneficial in this scenario as it can prevent data selected by a thread is not double processed by another thread.

However upon testing via SQL Developer, the query doesn't seems to lock the record. Here's a query:

```
select campaign_cd, id from test_input_table where id like '%0_X' for update skip locked
```

I have the above query run on my SQL Developer, and my colleague run on his after that, both of us managed to select the same set of data.

Any thoughts of why is that the case? Is it because of we're using SQL Developer to test?

Our database version is 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit.

**Update**

The SQL Developer version used is Version 4.0.3.16

There is nothing extra done, we just tried to run the query one after another in different machine. Both query returns the same set of data.

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer? I can't duplicate that with 4.1.0.18, even with autocommit turned on in the preferences, but an earlier version might behave differently perhaps. Are you running it standalone, in a block, as a statement, as a script? Are there any other statements run at the same time? Can you see the same effect if you try this in SQL\*Plus?

Comment: @AlexPoole I confirm, there isn't any issue in SQL Developer 3.2.20.10 either. And I don't think it is an issue specific to any client tool.

Comment: @ipohfly Could you please post a working test case. Just looking at the posted query, nothing could be said.

Comment: Hi, i'd added the SQL Developer version number. Nothing specific other than running the query. The issue is, after i selected the records, the other SQL Developer managed to select the same set of data, although both of us is running with the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` criteria

Comment: One thing though, both of us is using the same schema and login, but in different machine. That should be considered as different session right? I checked the `v$session` view and there are 2 records there.

Comment: Did you try to execute the query with SQL*Plus to narrow down the problem?

Comment: 1. try `for update nowait`, 2. ensure you have autocommit off, 3. try to enclose the SQL statement with `begin` and `end` and execute as script

Comment: I can't duplicate with 4.0.3.16 either. The only way I can see you seeing something like that is if both sessions inserted (and didn't commit) the same data you're seeing from your query, but that doesn't seem to be what you are describing. So we're missing something from the picture, I think.

Comment: i think i found the cause. It seems that in SQL Developer, when we run that, it will only locked the first 50 rows of data, unless we scroll to bottom. The data that my colleague see is actually the left over from the 50 rows that i had locked initially.